# Getting RSS item <description> with XmlNodeList

Tags: c#, xml, rss

I'm trying to get the description from a podcast item in an rss feed but I want it to start reading after any extra tags after the description such as a paragraph tag.

```
XmlNodeList xmlNodeListDesc = myXmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("description");
List<Podd> poddLista = new List<Podd>();
for (int i = 2; i < xmlNodeListDur.Count; i++) 
{
    podd.description = xmlNodeListDesc[i].InnerText;
    poddLista.Add(podd);
}
```

```
< description>< ![ CDATA [< p >Desired text< / p >]]> < / description>
```

My current code would start reading after CDATA so `< p >` and any style tags would be included in the description.

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve], specifically a sample of the XML you want to parse (as text)?

Comment: I tried to but when i could not get it format correctly and i was not allowed to embed a image yet...

Comment: You should never embed XML or other text as an image, see see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.  You can surround your XML with a sequence of three back-quotes to format it literally.  I edited your question to add it in, so could you go back and add in the "real" XML?  See also [Posting XML in Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17940).